# How can I extract the values after = in my string with Perl?

Tags: perl, string, extract

I have a string like this

```
field1=1 field2=2 field3=abc
```

I want to ouput this as

```
2,1,abc
```

Any ideas as to how I can go about this?  I can write a small C or Java program to do this, trying I'm trying to find out a simple way to do it in Perl.

Comment: Did you really mean to swap **`1`** and **`2`** above?

Comment: Does this have anything to do with HTTP query strings? If this is a roundabout question to ask that, or if you can deal with ampersands or semi-colons separating the fields, then you could use any one of numerous CGI modules on CPAN.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

# Input string
my $string = "field1=1 field2=2 field3=abc";
# Split string into a list of "key=value" strings
my @pairs = split(/\s+/,$string);
# Convert pair strings into hash
my %hash = map { split(/=/, $_, 2) } @pairs;
# Output hash
printf "%s,%s,%s\n", $hash{field2}, $hash{field1}, $hash{field3};   # => 2,1,abc
# Output hash, alternate method
print join(",", @hash{qw(field2 field1 field3)}), "\n";
```

Comment: +1 for not resorting to the regex hammer.  However: split(/\s+/,$string) is also more simply expressed as split(' ',$string)

Comment: True, as long as there are single spaces only.

Answer (score 6):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $string = 'field1=1 field2=2 field3=abc';
my @values = ($string =~ m/=(\S+)/g);
print join(',', @values), "\n";
```

Comment: This outputs the fields in the wrong order.
Minor nitpick: it also won't work if any of the values contain an equal sign.

Answer (score 2):

Use `m//g` in list context:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $x = "field1=1 field2=2 field3=abc";

if ( my @matches = $x =~ /(?:field[1-3]=(\S+))/g ) {
    print join(',', @matches), "\n";
}

__END__
```

Output:

```
C:\Temp> klm
1,2,abc
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 $_='field1=1 field2=2 field3=abc';
 $,=',';
 say /=(\S+)/g
```

Let's play Perl golf :D

Comment: If we're playing golf... `perl -E "$_='field1=1 field2=2 field3=abc';$,=',';say /=(\S+)/g"`

Answer (score 1):

There's several ways you can do that:

- Regex match

> ```
> my $s = "field1=1 field2=2 field3=abc";
> $s =~ /field1=(\w*) field2=(\w*) field3=(\w*)$/; //pick out each field
> print $1,$2,$3;'
> ```

```
12abc
```

- Split the string on match

> ```
> my $s = "field1=1 field2=2 field3=abc"; 
> my @arr = split / /, $s; print @arr,"\n"; //make an array of name=value pairs
> my @vals = map { @pairs = split /=/, $_; $pairs[1] } @arr;  //get the values only from each pair
> print @vals'
> ```

```
field1=1field2=2field3=abc
12abc
```

- Split and put in a hash (I think that's the most useful one)

> ```
> my $s = "field1=1 field2=2 field3=abc"; 
> my @arr = split / /, $s;  
> my %pairs = map { split=/, $_; } @arr; 
> print $pairs{field1}, $pairs{field2}, $pairs{field3}
> ```

```
12abc
```

Answer (score 1):

```
my $str = 'field1=1 field2=2 field3=abc';
print(join(',', map { (split('=', $_))[1] } split(' ', $str)));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you actually need both the keys and the values. I would put them into a hash. You could just capture both sides of the "`=`", and put directly into the hash.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $str = 'field1=1 field2=2 field3=abc';

my %fields = $str =~ / (\S+) \s* = \s* (\S+) /xg;

use YAML;
print Dump \%fields
```

```
---
field1: 1
field2: 2
field3: abc
```

For further information please read [`perldoc perlre`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html).

If you are just a beginner, you may want to read [`perldoc perlretut`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html).

Answer (score -1):

Assuming your ordering was a typo:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict; use warnings;

my $str='a=1 b=2 c=abc';
my @v;
while ($str =~ /=(\S+)/g) {
    push @v, $1;
}
print join (',', @v);
```

Comment: There's no need to loop. You can grab all the matches at once by using `m//g` in list context.

Answer (score -1):

Perl is definitely the right tool for this.

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

$str = "field1=1 field2=2 field3=abc";
$str =~ /field1=(\S+)\ field2=(\S+)\ field3=(\S+)/;
print "$1,$2,$3", "\n";
```

Answer (score -1):

```
my $a = "field1=1 field2=2 field3=abc";
my @f = split /\s*\w+=/, $a;
shift(@f);
print join(",", @f), "\n";
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$string="field1=1 field2=2 field3=abc";
@s=split /\s+/,$string;
$temp=$s[1];$s[1]=$s[0];$s[0]=$temp;
foreach (@s){s/.*=//; push(@a,$_ );}
print join(",",@a);
```

Answer (score -1):

You could make use of `\K` to reset the start of the match and then match 1 or more non whitespace characters.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $str = 'field1=1 field2=2 field3=abc';
my @values = $str =~ m/=\K\S+/g;

print join(',', @values), "\n";
```

Output

```
1,2,abc
```

If you want to switch the first and the second item to get `2,1,abc`  in the output you can check if @values has at least 2 items to reverse:

```
if (@values > 1) {
    @values[0, 1] = reverse @values[0, 1];
}
```

Note that `\S` can also match an equals sign. If you want to exclude that you can use a negated character class `[^\s=]`